# Grep and regex: inconsistent behaviour

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I was working on the Linux box A and I run this:

```
grep '^\S*\s-' access_log
```

That displayed some lines, as expected.

Then I moved to the machine B and I launched exactly the same command. But this time it didn't work.
I had to launch this in order to get done what I needed:

```
grep '^[^ ]* -' access_log
```

Before succeeding, I tried all of these but with no luck:

```
grep '^\S* -' access_log  
grep '^\S*\s-' access_log      
grep -e '^\S* -' access_log   
grep -E '^\S* ' access_log
```

It looks like machine B doesn't understand the metacharacters \S and \s.

Both of the boxes were running: grep 2.5.1 and bash 3.2.25

How is that possible?

Cheers,
Dan

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514135/bash-regular-expression-cant-seem-to-match-any-of-s-s-d-d-w-w-etc is about Bash's built-in regular expressions, but basically applies to traditional regex tools like `grep`, too.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the [grep man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep). It seems that if you can use things like `\s` you are using Perl regular expressions. Which are used when the `-P` option is passed to grep. So it may be that that option is set automatically on machine A and not on machine B. The reason for that may be some alias, or the option is set in `GREP_OPTIONS`.