# What do \S, \W, \D stand for in regex?

Tags: regex, shell

In shell scripting we have `\t` for tab, `\s` for whitespace, `\w` for word.
What are `\W` (capital W) and `\D` (capital D) used for?

Comment: None of these are generally available in shell script. Bash might support some of them if it was compiled with GNU libc; POSIX shell script does not have a regular expression facility at all (though of course you can run external tools like `grep`, `sed`, or Perl, where the former two also do not _portably_ support these Perlisms).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514135/bash-regular-expression-cant-seem-to-match-any-of-s-s-d-d-w-w-etc for some workarounds.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`\W` is the opposite of `\w` and `\D` is the opposite of `\d`.

It's just like `\S` is the opposite of `\s`.

`\W` and `\D` respectively will match what `\w` and `\d` respectively don't match.

You can have a look at [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for some more explanation.

`\w` typically matches `[A-Za-z0-9_]`  (ignoring the foreign characters)

`\W` thus matches `[^A-Za-z0-9_]`

And since

`\d` typically matches `[0-9]`  (ignoring the foreign digits)

`\D` thus matches `[^0-9]`

Comment: This answer has been added to the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Character Classes".

Answer (score 6):

According to the [manual](http://turtle.ee.ncku.edu.tw/docs/perl/manual/pod/perlre.html):

```
\W  Match a non-word character
\D  Match a non-digit character
```

`\W` matches any character that is not matched by `\w`. Likewise `\D` matches any character that is not matched by `\d`.