# Regex match word not immediately preceded by another word but possibly preceded by that word before

Tags: python, regex

I need to match all strings that contain one word of a list, but only if that word is not **immediately** preceded by another specific word.
I have this regex:

`.*(?<!forbidden)\b(word1|word2|word3)\b.*`

that is still matching a sentence like `hello forbidden word1` because `forbidden` is matched by `.*`. But if I remove the `.*` I am not anymore matching strings like `hello word1`, which I want to match.

Note that I want to match a string like `forbidden hello word1`.

Could you suggest me how to fix this problem?

Comment: just get rid of anchors, they serve no purpose here anyways

Comment: @gog you are right, but this does not solve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look into [word boundaries](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-regex/python-regex-word-boundary/) `\bword` can never touch a *word character* to the left.

To disallow `(word1|word2|word3)` if not preceded by `forbidden` and

- one `\W` ([non word character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011161/what-do-s-w-d-stand-for-in-regex/19011185#19011185))

  ```
  ^.*?\b(?<!forbidden\W)(word1|word2|word3)\b.*
  ```

  [See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dDKJIi/2)
- multiple `\W`

  Lookbehinds need to be of [fixed length](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#limitbehind) in Python regex. To get around this, an idea is to use `\W*` outside preceded by `(?<!\W)` for setting the position to look behind.

  ```
  ^.*?(?<!forbidden)(?<!\W)\W*\b(word1|word2|word3)\b.*
  ```

  [Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/6nDYiJ/2) (in multiline demo I used `[^\w\n]` instead `\W` for not skipping over lines)

  Certainly *variable-width* lookbehind, such as `(?<!forbidden\W+)` would be more comfortable. [PyPI Regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) > [`import regex AS re`](https://pypi.org/project/regex-as-re-globally/) supports lookbehind of variable length: [See this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e.*%3f%5cb%28%3f%3c!forbidden%5cW%2b%29%28word1%7cword2%7cword3%29%5cb.*&i=word1%0d%0aforbidden+word1%0d%0aanother+word1%0d%0aword2+and+more+words%0d%0aforbidden...%3a+word3%0d%0aforbidden+hello+word1%0d%0asomething+else&o=m)

*Note*: If you do not [capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) anything, a `(?:` [non-capturing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions) can be used as well.

Answer (score 0):

This one seems to work well :

```
^.*\b(?!(?:forbidden|word[1-3])\b)\w+ (word[1-3]).*$
```

`\b(?!(?:forbidden|word[1-3])\b)\w+` checks for multiple following words that are not `forbidden` or `word[1-3]`.

So it matches `hi forbidden hello word1 test` but not `hi hello forbidden word2 test`.

Comment: Have you try this: "hi forbidden hello word1 test forbidden word1"

Comment: Oh you're right, `^.*` and `.*$` are incorrect so it's not working with entire strings.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is match entire string. Try this:

[Regex test](https://regex101.com/r/fTbCg6/1)

`^(.(?<!forbidden (word1|word2|word3)\b))*((?<!forbidden )\b(word1|word2|word3)\b)+(.(?<!forbidden (word1|word2|word3)\b))*$`

The knowledge is from this thread [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)

I've just reversed the order of look-around

`^(.(?<!forbidden (word1|word2|word3)\b))*` to discard any string that has pattern `forbidden (word1|word2|word3)`

`((?<!forbidden )\b(word1|word2|word3)\b)` is what you defined

But I just can't understand why do you need this requirement.