# Python regex to match string not preceded by another string, but with other words in between

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I tried the accepted answer to [Regex match word not immediately preceded by another word but possibly preceded by that word before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72741712/regex-match-word-not-immediately-preceded-by-another-word-but-possibly-preceded) but that didn't work.

```py
>>> re.search('(?<!nonland) onto the battlefield', "When you cast this spell, reveal the top X cards of your library. You may put a nonland permanent card with mana value X or less from among them onto the battlefield. Then shuffle the rest into your library.") 
<re.Match object; span=(144, 165), match=' onto the battlefield'>
>>> re.search('^.*?(?<!nonlaxnd)(?<!\W)\W*\bonto the battlefield\b.*', "When you cast this spell, reveal the top X cards of your library. You may put a nonland permanent card with mana value X or less from among them onto the battlefield. Then shuffle the rest into your library.")
>>> # basically only match good when no bad:
>>> re.search('(?<!bad) good', "other bad other good.") 
<re.Match object; span=(15, 20), match=' good'>
```

Comment: That other question is about one word *immediately* preceded by the other. You can't use the same solution if there can be other text in between.

Comment: And explain what the expected result is for each example.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this with a single regexp. You need to put `.*` in the negative lookbehind, but Python regexp requires that lookbehind be fixed-length.

Comment: Do you have to do this with a single regexp? It's easier to match when `bad.*good`, and invert the test.

Comment: That would match any string without good.

Comment: `if re.search('good', string) and not re.search('bad.*good', string):`

Comment: That's less code than adding regex from PyPI so i'd accept that as an answer.

Comment: You could use [`^(?:(?!bad).)*good`](https://regex101.com/r/jSKJvK/1)

Comment: How about, _non(?!land).+?onto the battlefield_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `in` being so simple explains why Python's built-in `re` module doesn't do variable-length lookbehind. There's also [the regex Nick suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77198484/python-regex-to-match-string-not-preceded-by-another-string-but-with-other-word?noredirect=1#comment136094456_77198484):

```py
>>> samples = ['other bad other good.', 'other good.']
>>> ['good' in s and not re.search('bad.*good', s) for s in samples]    
[False, True]
>>> [re.search("^(?:(?!bad).)*good", s) for s in samples]     
[None, <re.Match object; span=(0, 10), match='other good'>]
```