# Python regex Get first element after specific string

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get the first number (int and float) after a specific pattern:

```
strings = ["Building 38 House 10",
           "Building : 10.5 house 900"]
for x in string:
    print(<rule>)
```

Wanted result:

```
'38'
'10.5'
```

I tried:

```
for x in strings:
    print(re.findall(f"(?<=Building).+\d+", x))
    print(re.findall(f"(?<=Building).+(\d+.?\d+)", x))
[' 38 House 10']
['10']
[' : 10.5 house 900']
['00']
```

But I'm missing something.

Comment: [`Building.*?([\d.]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/KvBfcs/1) or simply [`[\d.]+`](https://regex101.com/r/KvBfcs/3) with `re.find()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a capture group:

```
\bBuilding[\s:]+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\bBuilding` Match the word `Building`
- `[\s:]+` Match 1+ whitespace chars or colons
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` Capture group 1, match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JarCKu/1)

```
import re
strings = ["Building 38 House 10",
           "Building : 10.5 house 900"]
pattern = r"\bBuilding[\s:]+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)"
for x in strings:
    m = re.search(pattern, x)
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))
```

Output

```
38
10.5
```

Answer (score 1):

An idea to use `\D` (negated `\d`) to match any [non-digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011161/what-do-s-w-d-stand-for-in-regex/19011185#19011185) in between and [capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) the number:

```
Building\D*\b([\d.]+)
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/NXRSvw/1) or [Python demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolYuruKQoMy@9WMFWIVrJqTQzJwXIUzC2UPDILy1OVTA0UNLhUkAAhBIroJyeqUIGWJmlgYFSLBdXWn6RQoVCZp4C1FArsNYCILtEoyhVLy0zLyUxJ0ejCG5KjItWTJJGdEyKXqy2ppKOQoWm5v//AA)

Just to mention, use [word boundaries `\b`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) around `Building` to match the full word.

Answer (score 0):

```
re.findall(r"(?<![a-zA-Z:])[-+]?\d*\.?\d+", x)
```

This will find all numbers in the given string.

If you want the first number only you can access it simply through indexing:

```
re.findall(r"(?<![a-zA-Z:])[-+]?\d*\.?\d+", x)[0]
```

Comment: That would include 10 and 900, which OP doesn't want.

Comment: You are right, edited the answer.