# Bash Regex with Quotes (BASH_REMATCH)

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I have this in a file:

```
<tr class="LightRow Center" style="height:auto;">
<td class="SmallText resultbadB" title="Non-Compliant/Vulnerable/Unpatched" style="width:20%">0</td>
<td class="SmallText resultgoodB" title="Compliant/Non-Vulnerable/Patched" style="width:20%">1</td>
<td class="SmallText errorB" title="Error" style="width:20%">0</td>
<td class="SmallText unknownB" title="Unknown" style="width:20%">0</td>
<td class="SmallText otherB" title="Inventory/Miscellaneous class, or Not Applicable/Not Evaluated result" style="width:20%">0</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to get at the text from this row:

```
<td class="SmallText resultbadB" title="Non-Compliant/Vulnerable/Unpatched" style="width:20%">0</td>
```

This is being done a shell script and I am trying to use the bash regular expressions.

I have tried this shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
REGEX_EXPR='\<td\ class=\"SmallText\ resultbadB\"\ title=\"Non-Compliant\/Vulnerable\/Unpatched\"\ style=\"width\:20\%\"\>\(.*\)\</td\>'

[[ /tmp/result.html =~ $REGEX_EXPR ]]
echo "output $?"
echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

However I get a no match response (1) on the `echo "output $?"` I have tried the following regex's as well.

```
REGEX_EXPR='<td class="SmallText resultbadB" title="Non-Compliant/Vulnerable/Unpatched" style="width:20%">\(.*\)</td>'
REGEX_EXPR='<td class="SmallText resultbadB" title="Non-Compliant/Vulnerable/Unpatched" style="width:20%">(.*)</td>'
```

And some other escape combinations, example, escaped just the quotes. Tried to define the variable in quotes and so on.

Any thoughts on where I am messing up?

'

Comment: Seems to be a a problem with the whitespaces in the file. Compare: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514135/bash-regular-expression-cant-seem-to-match-s-s-etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not in the regex, but in what you try to match it against.

```
[[ /tmp/result.html =~ $REGEX_EXPR ]]
```

This means the string `/tmp/result.html` is being matched, not the contents of the file. To match line by line, you'll need a loop:

```
while read line ; do
    if [[ "$line" =~ $REGEX ]] ; then 
         ...
    fi
done < /tmp/result.html
```

Comment: I am like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=khSIYmTzt6U was so focused on the regex that I didnt pay attention to what I was searching in.