# Why can't I use ^\s with grep?

Tags: regex, grep

Both of the regexes below work In my case.

```
grep \s
grep ^[[:space:]]
```

However all those below fail. I tried both in git bash and putty.

```
grep ^\s
grep ^\s*
grep -E ^\s
grep -P ^\s
grep ^[\s]
grep ^(\s)
```

The last one even produces a syntax error.

If I try `^\s` in debuggex it works.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/GR8p1NvSAdFBGdZZ)

How do I find lines starting with whitespace characters with `grep` ? Do I *have* to use `[[:space:]]` ?

Comment: Are you using quotes at all? Without quoting, bash will 'eat' the escape of `\s` and you will need a second `grep ^\\s ...`

Comment: You're right ! with `\\s` it works ! But I don't get why ... Well if you put it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: You should alway quote every argument to every command unless you have a specific reason not to and fully understand all the implications. Quote using `'` by default, then `"` if necessary (e.g. to let a shell variable expand) and finally no quote if absolutely necessary (e.g. to allow word splitting, globbing and file name expansion).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash Regular Expression -- Can't seem to match \s, \S, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514135/bash-regular-expression-cant-seem-to-match-s-s-etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep \s` works for you because your input contains `s`. Here, you escape `s` and it matches the `s`, since it is not parsed as a whitespace matching regex escape. If you use `grep ^\\s`, you will match a string starting with whitespace since the `\\` will be parsed as a literal `\` char.

A better idea is to enable POSIX ERE syntax with `-E` and  quote the pattern:

```
grep -E '^\s' <<< "$s"
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/7BqPkp):

```
s=' word'
grep ^\\s <<< "$s"
# =>  word
grep -E '^\s' <<< "$s"
# =>  word
```

Comment: `\s` is a PRCE, not an ERE.  It's supported by GNU `grep` but most other `grep` implementations will interpret `\s` as `s`.

Comment: @Kusalananda I know, I meant a GNU grep. I only test with GNU grep, I am an Ubuntu user. Other implementations are too buggy from what I have seen for more than a year here on SO.

Comment: I don't even need any flag, it works with  `grep '^\s'`

Comment: @NicolasSeiller True, but it is just for convenience. If you use `+` or `{}`, you won't have to escape them.

Comment: `\s` has nothing to do with EREs or BREs - it'll work as shorthand for `[[:space:]]` in any regexp flavor if your grep (or other tool) version supports that shorthand and if it doesn't then it won't.

Comment: @EdMorton Re: "it'll work as shorthand for `[[:space:]]`": is there a manual / documentation that specifies that?

Comment: @pmor The man pages for tools that support it will state that. Generally any GNU version of a mandatory POSIX tool such as grep, sed, or awk will support it while most others won't. Many non-POSIX tools such as perl, python, or ruby will support it.

Comment: @EdMorton FYI: in ERE in bracket expression "[The characters $, *, ., [, and \ are normally not special within list](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html#Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions)". Hence, `[\s=]` matches ``\`` or `s` instead of matching space characters.

Comment: @pmor that's the GNU sed manual you're reading, not the POSIX spec for EREs, and the meaning of `\s` inside a bracket expression is different from outside of one.

Comment: @EdMorton OK. In [grep's documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html) I cannot find whether ``\`` is special within a bracket expression. However, tests show that it is not: `echo "x y" | egrep "x[\s=]+y"` prints nothing, while `echo "x\y" | egrep "x[\s=]+y"` prints `x\y`. `egrep --version` prints `grep (GNU grep) 3.7`.

Comment: @pmor I don't know why you're telling me these things. If you're curious about regexps, the POSIX definition for regexps is at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html and both BRE and ERE bracket expressions in particular are defined at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05. If you have a question about any of that then please post a question.

Comment: If you're specifically interested in my earlier comment about `\s` then see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04_02 for why I said it's meaning has nothing to to with BREs or EREs. `s` is an ordinary character and "The interpretation of an ordinary character preceded by an unescaped <backslash> ( '\\' ) is undefined, except in the context of a bracket expression (see ERE Bracket Expression)." and so GNU or any other tool provider else can define `\s` to mean whatever they like in that context.