# Bash regex matching "0xffffffc0006e0584 is in some_function (/path/to/my/file.c:93)."

Tags: regex, bash

In a Bash script I'm writing, I need to capture the `/path/to/my/file.c` and `93` in this line:

```
0xffffffc0006e0584 is in some_function (/path/to/my/file.c:93).
0xffffffc0006e0584 is in another_function(char *arg1, int arg2)  (/path/to/my/other_file.c:94).
```

With the help of regex101.com, I've managed to create this Perl regex:

```
^(?:\S+\s){1,5}\((\S+):(\d+)\)
```

but I hear that Bash doesn't understand `\d` or `?:`, so I came up with this:

```
^([:alpha:]+[:space:]){1,5}\(([:alpha:]+):([0-9]+)\)
```

But when I try it out:

```
line1="0xffffffc0006e0584 is in some_function (/path/to/my/file.c:93)."
regex="^([:alpha:]+[:space:]){1,5}\(([:alpha:]+):([0-9]+)\)"
[[ $line1 =~ $regex ]]
echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
```

I don't get any match. What am I doing wrong? How can I write a Bash-compatible regex to do this?

Comment: Try it like this `^([[:alnum:]_]+[[:space:]]){1,5}\(((\/[[:alpha:]]+)+)\.[[:alpha:]]:([[:digit:]]+)\)\.$` https://regex101.com/r/Lra9ue/1 The values are in group 2 and 4 `echo ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}` and `echo ${BASH_REMATCH[4]}`

Comment: Thanks @Thefourthbird, any reason why you had to partition the filename and the extension ?

Comment: That is because the repetition of `/` and 1+ alpha chars in a group to match a path like structure. The last repetition of the group will hold the match, in this case `/file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, Bash uses POSIX ERE and does not support `\d` shorthand character class, nor does it support non-capturing groups. See [more regex features unsupported in POSIX ERE/BRE in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48898886/3832970).

Use

```
.*\((.+):([0-9]+)\)
```

Or even (if you need to grab the first `(...)` substring in a string):

```
\(([^()]+):([0-9]+)\)
```

**Details**

- `.*` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible (may be omitted, only necessary if there are other `(...)` substrings and you only need to grab the *last* one)
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `(.+)` - Group 1 (`${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`): any 1+ chars as many as possible
- `:` - a colon
- `([0-9]+)` - Group 2 (`${BASH_REMATCH[2]}`): 1+ digits
- `\)` - a `)` char.

See the [Bash demo](https://ideone.com/2CkuPz) (or [this one](https://ideone.com/AxvIi0)):

```
test='0xffffffc0006e0584 is in some_function (/path/to/my/file.c:93).'
reg='.*\((.+):([0-9]+)\)'
# reg='\(([^()]+):([0-9]+)\)' # This also works for the current scenario
if [[ $test =~ $reg ]]; then
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]};
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[2]};
fi
```

Output:

```
/path/to/my/file.c
93
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first pattern you use `\S+` which matches a non whitespace char. That is a broad match and will also match for example `/` which is not taken into account in the second pattern.

The pattern starts with `[:alpha:]` but the first char is a 0. You could use `[:alnum:]` instead. Since the repetition should also match `_` that could be added as well.

Note that when using a quantifier for a capturing group, the group captures the last value of the iteration. So when using `{1,5}` you use that quantifier only for the repetition. Its value would be `some_function`

You might use:

```
^([[:alnum:]_]+[[:space:]]){1,5}\(((/[[:alpha:]]+)+\.[[:alpha:]]):([[:digit:]]+)\)\.$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YaP6sp/1) | [Bash demo](https://ideone.com/q98DKv)

Your code could look like

```
line1="0xffffffc0006e0584 is in some_function (/path/to/my/file.c:93)."
regex="^([[:alnum:]_]+[[:space:]]){1,5}\(((/[[:alpha:]]+)+\.[[:alpha:]]):([[:digit:]]+)\)\.$"
[[ $line1 =~ $regex ]]
echo ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
echo ${BASH_REMATCH[4]}
```

Result

```
/path/to/my/file.c
93
```

Or a bit shorter version using `\S` and the values are in group 2 and 3

```
^([[:alnum:]_]+[[:space:]]){1,5}\((\S+\.[[:alpha:]]):([[:digit:]]+)\)\.$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `([[:alnum:]_]+[[:space:]]){1,5}` Repeat 1-5 times what is captured in group 1
- `\(` match `(`
- `(\S+\.[[:alpha:]])` Capture **group 2** Match 1+ non whitespace chars, `.` and an alphabetic character
- `:` Match `:`
- `([[:digit:]]+)` Capture **group 3** Match 1+ digits
- `\)\.` Match `).`
- `$` End of string

See this page about [bracket expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WhHirC/1)