# \d fails to match numbers

Tags: regex, bash

In bash script, `/d` fails while same worked with `[0-9]`

```
ip="106.990.120.78"

regex1="^(\d+\.){3}\d+$"
regex2="^([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+$"

if [[ $ip =~ $regex2 ]]; then
  echo "success"
else
  echo "fail"
fi
```

Both patterns work same in https://regex101.com/r/cNhDAL/1

/d also used for numeric that are in string. Why such behavior in bash shell?

Note: I am just matching the pattern only, not checking either IP is valid or not

Comment: There are multiple implementations of regex, the one you're using doesn't parse `\d` as the numerics class' shorthand notation. More info [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) on the two regex flavours defined by POSIX

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48898886/10248678).

Comment: `d=[[:digit:]]` and than do: 
`regex1="^($d{1,3}\.){3}$d{1,3}$"`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thanks its also worthful. Does this way only work in bash or can work in other langs also?

Comment: If you use zsh instead of bash, you can get support for pcre dialect regular expressions, btw.

Comment: @dahiya_boy will not work in other languages. I.E: in JavaScript  `[[:digit:]]` is invalid syntax.

Comment: @Shawn Thanks for info, I not aware of such limitations, i will not for future.

Comment: Shawn oguzismail Aaron RokoC.Buljan      thanks for sharing knowledge.

Comment: you could always create a replacer: wherever you detect a `\d` (and if it's not preceded by ` \ \`) and if the ENV is bash - replace it with `[[:digit:]]` etc etc for the other special references.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan  a/c to answer shared by oguz there are many chars that are not supported by bash, Is there any blog that specifies the replacement in bash so that I can refer from there.

Comment: @dahiya_boy `\d \D \s \S \w \W` https://stackoverflow.com/a/48898886/383904