# gzip files based on regular expression

Tags: regex, command, gzip

I would like to gzip all files in a directory if the file name matches a regular expression. Is there a way I could do something similar to:

`gzip \b[^2\W]{2,}\b`

Right now, when I do that it gives me an error because it does not know that I want to match a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
find -maxdepth 1 -regex '.*\b[^2[^_[:alnum:]]]{2,}\b.*' -exec gzip {} +
```

The `-maxdepth 1` prevents `find` from traversing subdirectories, which is otherwise its default behavior and primary purpose.

The `-regex` argument needs to match the whole file name, so I added `.*` on both sides.

Comment: This is a good idea, but you messed up the syntax in a couple of places. The argument to `-exec` should not be `$1` (and anyway, basically [always quote file name variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)) but `{} +`, and `find` will traverse subdirectories, so you will want to add a `-maxdepth 1` to prevent that.

Comment: We are generally advised to avoid making code changes without leaving a comment. I'll be happy to change those things if you are unable to, with your permission.

Comment: I see that this post was just edited. In both commands, I received this error: `FIND: Parameter format not correct`

Comment: @NathanDai What OS are you running?

Comment: Windows with Cygwin. That probably explains the error.

Comment: Yup.  Had the same problem myself in school.  I only run Linux at home... Unfortunately a reinstall is required to add packages to Cygwin. See [https://superuser.com/questions/304541/how-to-install-new-packages-on-cygwin]

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear which shell you are asking about. Bash has [extended glob patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) which however are still not regular expressions. For proper regex, you will want to try looping over the files:

```sh
pat='\b[^_[:alnum:]]{2,}\b'
for file in ./*; do
    if [[ "$file" =~ $pat ]]; then
        gzip "$file"
    fi
done
```

Bash does not support the Perl-compatible `\W` (which includes `2` anyway) so I switched to the POSIX character class `[^_[:alnum:]]` which is basically equivalent.  Perhaps see also [Bash Regular Expression -- Can't seem to match any of \s \S \d \D \w \W etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514135/bash-regular-expression-cant-seem-to-match-any-of-s-s-d-d-w-w-etc/48898886#48898886)

In the general case, you can always use a separate regular expression tool.

```sh
printf '%s\0' ./* |
perl -0lne 'print if /\b[^2\W]{2,}\b/' |
xargs -0 gzip
```

The shenanigans with `\0` bytes is to support arbitrary file names robustly (think file names with newlines in them, etc); see also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020

Comment: The OP does not have perl or find installed on the Cygwin or Msys install.

Comment: This is your win what can I do for you? I was about to delete it so you could post the correct answer. Sorry.

Comment: It's not like I'm starved for rep (-; but an upvote would be appreciated.

Comment: Sigh, people continue to think Windows is an operating system.

Comment: In 96, NT4 had promise with RISC HAL and POSIX support.