# Regex matches but script fails unexpectedly?

Tags: regex, bash

I have this regex, to match version numbers:

```
^[1-9]\d{0,1}\.(?!0\d)\d{1,3}\.(?!0\d)\d{1,4}$
```

Regex itself works and matches "1.0.0" when checked on [RegexChecker](https://www.regextester.com/107384)
However, when I try to wrap same regex in a bash script, my code goes in "else" condition. I fail to understand why ?

```
#!/bin/bash
VERSION='1.0.0'
MATCH_PATTERN='^[1-9]\d{0,1}\.(?!0\d)\d{1,3}\.(?!0\d)\d{1,4}$'
if [[ $VERSION =~ $MATCH_PATTERN ]]; then
  :
else
  echo "Version number format is wrong."
  exit 1
fi
```

I tried running with debugger using `set -x` but no luck. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Your regex is probably a PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions). From `man bash`: *the string to the right of the operator is considered a POSIX extended regular expression*

Comment: See ["Bash Regular Expression -- Can't seem to match any of `\s` `\S` `\d` `\D` `\w` `\W` etc"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514135/bash-regular-expression-cant-seem-to-match-any-of-s-s-d-d-w-w-etc) and ["Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)

Comment: Aside: see [correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization) then rename `VERSION` and `MATCH_PATTERN`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bash shell regex is [POSIX extended regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX) and does not support `\d` for digits or `(?!...)` for negative lookaheads

`\d` can be replaced with either `[0-9]` or `[:digits:]`

`(?!0\d)` can be replaced with an alternation of either 0 or a number not starting with 0 `(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,2})`

The pattern `^[1-9][0-9]{0,1}\.(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,2})\.(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,3})$` should match the noted PCRE expression.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
VERSION='1.0.0'
MATCH_PATTERN='^[1-9][0-9]{0,1}\.(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,2})\.(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,3})$'
if [[ $VERSION =~ $MATCH_PATTERN ]]; then
  :
else
  echo "Version number format is wrong."
  echo 1
fi
```